# how to create a login application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am making a login page, where the user can login with the same username and password provided by them.

I have to post the username ad password provided by the user to the server using PHP. The PHP page will validate the detail with the server and post me back the answer, and I have to get that answer and allow the user to login.

I have tried the following code but it's not working:

```
NSString *firstname = Firstname.text;
NSString *lastname = Lastname.text;
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fname=%@&lname=%@",firstname,lastname];
NSString *hostStr =@"http://yoursite.com/iphone/validateiphone.php";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if ([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"YES"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorised" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];    
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Invalid Username and password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
Firstname.text=nil;
Lastname.text=nil;
```

Comment: check the server reply.i.e print the serverOutput string.Then check whether you are getting the correct reply or not

Comment: when appending "post" string to "host" string, aren't you missing "?" character? if I am not mistaken, your hostString will look like:
http://yoursite.com/iphone/validateiphone.phpfname=something&lastname=somethingelse instead of http://yoursite.com/iphone/validateiphone.phpf?name=something&lastname=somethingelse

Comment: nothing is found in serverOutput........

Comment: use this instead and try please,
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?fname=%@&lname=%@",firstname,lastname];

Comment: futur.....i tried that i getting the value yes but along with the mysql table id for eg:56yes; please help me

Answer (score 2):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` doesn't do what you think it does. It will not perform HTTP requests etc. It will only access files in the local file system by URL. So you're not actually performing a HTTP request with your code.

`NSURLConnection` is the canonical API for doing HTTP on iOS.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yoursite.com/iphone/validateiphone.php"];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fname=%@&lname=%@",firstname,lastname];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPBody:[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

Then you need to implemenet the various NSURLConnectionDelegate methods to get notified if the request fails, when the request finishes, etc.

Alternatively, use a synchronous request in a thread. Don't do synchronous requests on the main thread, it'll block your UI.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // ....
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responseBody = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req 
                                                 returningResponse:&response 
                                                             error:&error];            

});
```

Comment: I'm hesitant to question someone with 10K+rep... but... are you sure about this: `dataWithContentsOfURL doesn't do what you think it does. It will not perform HTTP requests etc`?

Comment: No prob :) Yes, I'm sure about that. EDIT: Not so sure about that anymore. The documentation doesn't specify, and there are hits on google claiming it does actually do HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I really think that you might need to check your url on this one.  Just use your browser on your Mac/PC to verify that you are calling the right URL.
Your string append gives the following

```
http://yoursite.com/iphone/validateiphone.phpfname="firstName"&lname="lastName"
```

Where "firstName" and "lastName" are the arguments that you pass in.  I believe that this is an incorrect php request, and you are missing the query argument or "?".  You might need to append a "?" somewhere in there. So Perhaps

```
http://yoursite.com/iphone/validateiphone.php?fname="firstName"&lname="lastName"
```

Then make sure you're logging out the values of dataURL & serverOutput to make sure you're getting back what you expect.

Edit:

From your comment you might not have understood what I was trying to convey. Test that the URL you are using does in fact work by pasting it into your browser address bar and viewing the source (if nothing is shown on the page). 
Secondly you should alter your code to look like the following, so you can see what's going on in the debug output window.

```
 NSLog( @"URL sending Request to: %@", hostStr ); //Log the address you are setting as the url to ensure that it is correct. (You should be able to copy this into your browser and get a result if it is correct.
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
     NSLog( @"dataURL value:%@", dataURL): //this will let yo know if there is anything in, also insert a breakpoint here and verify that dataURL is not equal to 0x0 (or nil).
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"serverOutput as NSString: %@", serverOutput);//again breakpoint this and make sure serverOutput is not 0x0.
```

Comment: i am send all the detail's properly through url ...but i am unable to fetch the echo send or message  send by php file....... nd i am not getting any data in my dataURL and in serverOutput.....please help me out.. thank you

Comment: @NileshJoshi is the url working in your browser on your Mac/PC? (You may need to view source to ensure that it is working if nothing is rendered to your browser window).

Comment: @NileshJoshi Also add the NSLog's that I've put into my above answer, especially the one regarding the output of hostStr. If the URL for hostStr is correct then you should be able to paste the output of that variable that NSLog prints out into your browsers address bar and it should work, that is if your php script is working in the first place. Verify that first.